# htaccess need help rewriting url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've been trying to rewrite my URL's with a htaccess file.
My project is using my index.php as it's basic controller.
I fetch the pages from the database with the get-value "naam".

Example: 
localhost/YourDesigns/YDCMS/index.php?naam=home   (this shows the homepage)
localhost/YourDesigns/YDCMS/index.php?naam=about  (this shows the about page)

Now i want to rewrite the URLS to be shown like this:
localhost/YourDesigns/YDCMS/home   (this shows the homepage)
localhost/YourDesigns/YDCMS/about  (this shows the about page)

I have done some htaccess stuff myself and i've successfully removed the "index.php" from the url, but the "naam" still remains.

How do i remove this?
This is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YourDesigns/YDCMS/index.php?naam=/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your way to see the process it's not totally right, if you want to show the url like you say `localhost/YourDesigns/YDCMS/home` you have to first replace the url inside your html content to that format, then by using a RewriteRule you call the correct path internally:

```
RewriteRule ^desired_url_path/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /base_url_path/index.php?naam=$1 [L]
```

this way when an user click on a link the Apache server will use the above regex to convert the url by a rule that basically says : everything after the base url is aparameter value to be passed on the index.php.
Naturally the regex can be modified to suit your needs, the one i've written above it's a basic string pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  
So if my project directory is localhost/yourdesigns/YDCMS/  
my htaccess will look like this?  

RewriteRule ^YourDesigns/YDCMS/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /YDCMS/index.php?naam=$1 [L]      (sorry, i still have to figure out how to do a line break in stackoverflow xD )

Comment: I've editted your code a bit (not sure if it's correct or not) but it works as intended now!  This is the result: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YourDesigns/YDCMS/index.php?naam=$1 [L]

Comment: yep, i think that's correct if you are using a xampp/lampp installation. just remember that the rule must be relative to your site base url and you're set :)