# Rewrite Query string in URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How to rewrite my website's url from "website.com/example.php?site=youtube" to "website.com/example/youtube" where site is a variable? 
Should i change the url in the php file too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess need help rewriting url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632017/htaccess-need-help-rewriting-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]*)$ /example.php?site=$1 [L]
```

That will leave you with the following URL: `http://website.com/example/youtube`. Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

Comment: Should i change the url in the php file too. Like i have something like this "site.php?website=youtube" .. Should i change it to "site/$variable"?? Otherwise its not working for me. I am stuck on this thing from last  2 weeks.

Comment: Yes you will need to put the correct variables and domain into the RewriteRule.

Comment: i have shared the code i am using the in the answer please review it.
and the rewrite rule i am using is RewriteRule ^site/([^/]*)$ /site.php?website=$1 [L].

Answer (score 0):

```
 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "" , "test");

 $query = "SELECT * FROM websites";

 $select_all_sites = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_sites)) {
          $site_title = $row['site_title'];

echo "<a class='item' href='site.php?website=$site_title'> $site_title</a>";
```

On the other page which is called site.php i am using this code to get the variable from the sites.php page

```
  function myname(){
  if(isset($_GET['website'])){
  $variable = $_GET['website'];
  echo $variable;
    }
  }
```